# Call an API at scheduled time which can be changed dynamically

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, cron

I have created an API which will return the list of all events that are upcoming in 24 hours. Now, at the start time of these events I have to schedule and API call which will send notifications to all the user. How can I achieve this using AWS cron or any other service?
I am using Spring boot in Java.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way without paying anything significant is to use lambda for scheduled events. You can simply call any API from Scheduled Lambda. Scheduling Lambda is straight forward but extremely easy if we use serverless framework. You can setup the lambda with schedule in 10 minutes. A cronjob like format is available to set the schedule.

Reference on how to schedule lambda using sls framework
https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/schedule

UPDATE:

When you use Serverless framework it sets up the whole framework for scheduling for you. Scheduling part is actually maintained by CloudWatch Events functionality. You can modify this CloudWatch events dynamically as per your needs.

Reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/ScheduledEvents.html

Comment: But how do I setup the lambda using dynamic times. The time and dates of the events will vary. @Hussain Mansoor

Comment: Updated my answer with the solution for dynamic part

Answer (score 0):

You can use Timer and TimerTask which java provides.
Ref -
http://www.java2s.com/Tutorials/Java/Java_Utilities/How_to_use_Java_Timer_and_TimerTask_to_schedule_a_task.htm